# ethernet protocol not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, ethernet, administrator

I was playing around trying to connect to the WiFi pineapple via WiFi again, and I screwed up my Ethernet by accident. The only adapter I can diagnose that has something wrong is Ethernet. Here are my network adapters:

[image: network adapters]

Here is the error I get when trying to diagnose it:

[image: error with network adapters]

When I try to fix it as an administrator:

[image: not able to fix error]

I also tried this in Command Prompt:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
Resetting Interface, OK!
Resetting Unicast Address, OK!
Resetting Neighbor, OK!
Resetting Path, OK!
Resetting , failed.
Access is denied.

Resetting , OK!
Restart the computer to complete this action.
```

At that point, I realize it's as if I don't have permission as an administrator to fix my own computer. I tried this command:

```
ipconfig /all >C:\pingresult.txt
```

In the outputted file I got this under the Ethernet sections:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-E6-D7-81-BE-DF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b4e2:623:6404:61de%6(Preferred) 
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.97.222(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 406120151
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-10-EB-26-34-E6-D7-81-BE-DF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::dcf5:8e1f:fb20:c7b2%4(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.75.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, December 26, 2015 11:34:00 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, December 27, 2015 12:04:00 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.75.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 50352214
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-10-EB-26-34-E6-D7-81-BE-DF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
       Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :     fe80::ed8b:970b:dc4c:dfa9%13(Preferred) 
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.66.1(Preferred) 
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
           Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, December 26, 2015 11:33:45 PM
       Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, December 27, 2015 12:03:45 AM
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
       DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.66.254
       DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 268456022
       DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-10-EB-26-34-E6-D7-81-BE-DF
       DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
       Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.66.2
       NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the drivers for the network card and then scan for hardware changes in the computer management console in Windows?

Comment: Could you provide a link to a YouTube video on how to do all of that so I can do it and fix my computer? When I scan for hardware changes, then do I get to reinstall the whole thing and along with it comes Ethernet? Is that the idea?

Comment: whatever it is, your title seems absurd

Comment: @Richie086   I don't see a "scan for hardware changes" in computer management, are you sure you got that right?  I see a "scan for hardware changes" in device manager(at least after teh name of the comp is clicked).

Comment: here ya go https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07ov3fR5YzA

Comment: I did that. It didn't work. Is there any way to reinstall every protocol that comes with windows. I tried doing a clean install of windows 10 and it still didn't work.

Comment: Geek Squad also couldn't fix it.

Comment: Geek squad could not fix it means nothing, those folks are some of the worst techs I've ever had the misfortune to meet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ethernet drivers with you, try to uninstall the ethernet driver and restart your computer.

After restarting your computer, check for the ethernet connection (In some computers some essential drivers automatically after you restart your PC).

If the problem still persists, install the ethernet driver and restart your PC again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing and using FixWin for Windows 10 and using all of the networking fixes, then restarting my computer.